# Is this translation, seen on a car, correct?

Tags: translation

Out for my early morning stroll, I saw a car, a Tesla I believe. It has one of those paint jobs where the colour changes depending on the angle you look at it, but basically pink.

Written on it, in quite big white characters and letters is:

别怕失败·大不了从头来过。
Life f***ing movies. (the offending f-word is actually written completely)

The translation doesn't seem quite right to me. :) How did they get "movies"?

Can you do better?

Comment: Life **is a** f***ing movie?

Comment: Maybe "人生如戏". This word is common. It means life is sometimes too dramatic, used to express the open-minded attitude when facing the f***ing frustrations.

Answer (score 6):

Just because there are two sentences side by side in two languages does not necessarily mean that one is a translation of the other. It can be a continuation of thoughts, ideas, but the writer somehow chooses to use a juxtaposition of languages for whatever effects they want to achieve. In this case, it's also one perfectly uplifting statement followed by one with a glaring swear word. Why? Only the writer knows.

I am sure you have heard songs that goes a whole stanza in Chinese, and then there's a line of English at the end. Well, it's the same idea.

The gist of this short paragraph is "Don't be afraid of failure. If worst comes to worst, you'll just start over. Life is like a movie."

Comment: Didn't think it may not be a translation! The English makes no sense!

Answer (score 1):

Google translate gives:

> The big deal is to start over

Which actually seems quite close to the "real" answer. However, many websites disagree and say "life is a movie" or "life is a f***ing movie" is the correct answer:

- [Djencn: 别怕失败·大不了从头来过](https://www.djnecn.com/%E5%88%AB%E6%80%95%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5%E5%A4%A7%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86%E4%BB%8E%E5%A4%B4%E6%9D%A5%E8%BF%87%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91.html)
- [Baidu: 别怕失败，大不了，从头再来](http://g13.baidu.com/s?word=%E5%88%AB%E6%80%95%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5%E5%A4%A7%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86%E9%87%8D%E6%96%B0%E6%9D%A5%E8%BF%87%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87&sa=brs_4&rq=%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E9%9A%BE%E5%85%8D%E4%BC%9A%E6%9C%89%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD&rsf=900002805&pqid=7803824911150637932&rqid=7803824911150637932&params_ssrt=node-san)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably like a metaphor. Life is just a TV show or movie. It doesn't matter we do something wrong because we can always start it over again. So to speak, we could always produce another movie since last one is not good.